# Display item below row in table on click

Tags: css, html-table, position, css-transitions

I have a table displaying some information. What I'd like to accomplish is to allow the user to click on a row, and have the note related to the info in that row display below that row.

I am trying to set it up so that I can use the nifty CSS transition feature, so just putting the note in a hidden, absolutely positioned row below the info row is out of the question. CSS transition doesn't act on the `position` style.

I've got it set up so that the note will be in a `div`. When the user clicks a row in the table, an `onClick` event calls up a Javascript function which makes the `div` visible. Now all I need is for the div to line up under the selected table row.

How could I get the table row's height and position? I figure I could use that to position the `div`. Or, is there a better way to do this?

Here's an example of what I've got:

```
<style>
    .emarNote{
                transition: all .3s linear;
                -o-transition: all .3s linear;
                -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
                -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
            }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showEmar(id)
    {
        if (document.getElementById("emarNote"+id).style.visibility == "hidden")
        {
            document.getElementById("emarNote"+id).style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("emarNote"+id).style.opacity = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("emarNote"+id).style.opacity = 0;
            document.getElementById("emarNote"+id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>

<table>
    <tr onClick="showEmar(1)">
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="emar1" class="emarNote" style="visibility:hidden; opacity:0; position:absolute;">
    note about info
</div>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery in this project?  That would probably be the easiest (though not necessarily *best*) way to accomplish your goal.  Reliably calculating height/width in a cross-browser way is a non-trivial task w/o a JS library to do it for you.

Comment: jQuery would be fine. I have sadly yet to learn much about it, so any new exposure would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st download [JQuery](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/11/jquery-1-4-4-release-notes/).
Then do something like below:

```
    <style>
    .emarNote{ background:#CCCCCC; }        
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.emarNote').hide();
    $('tbody', '#myTable').click(function(event) {
        tr_ID = $(event.target).parent().attr('id');
        $('#' + tr_ID + '-info').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>

<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>Info</td>
        <td>Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="row1-info" class="emarNote">MORE INFO would be really cool and such</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

NOTE: Replace "fadeToggle" with "slideToggle" to acheive a slide effect. Also, I really think you should read up a bit on JQuery to fully understand the solution. You will find that it is actually quite easy to understand once you get the basics.

Comment: fantastic, thanks! Yeah, I definitely need to make time to learn it. Someday, hopefully, I will.